# MongoDB compare current day with day in mongodb and insertOne() if not match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, upsert

I'm trying to update, create or replace some field in my collection depending on 2 conditions.
here is what I have:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    userId:ObjectId("61965bead6af120015c7e9cc"),
    date: ISODate("2021-11-25T16:04:35.606Z"),
    ip: "100.000.000.0"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("11934e000102030405000111"),
    userId:ObjectId("61965bead6af120015c7e9cd"),
    date: ISODate("2021-11-25T14:08:32.992Z"),
    ip: "200.000.000.0"
  }
]
```

My var is :

userId : req.user._id

date : new Date()

ip : req.socket.remoteAddress

Sorry, editing, I reformulate:
What I need is to create new entry with userId(not unique) IF date is not the same day as the date in mongo else do nothing

Not good :

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      dateinDB: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: ISODate("2021-11-23T16:04:35.606Z"),
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      },
      current: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: new Date(),
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$userId",
              "$req.user._id"
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $ne: [
                  "$dateinDB",
                  "$current"
                ]
              },
              then: {
                date: new Date()
              },
              else: {
                date: "test"
              }
            }
          },
          else: {
            "userId": "$req.user._id",
            "date": new Date(),
            "ip": "$req.socket.remoteAddress"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

create :

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "current": "2021-11-23",
    "date": {
      "date": "test"
    },
    "dateinDB": "2021-11-23"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("11934e000102030405000111"),
    "current": "2021-11-23",
    "date": {
      "date": "test"
    },
    "dateinDB": "2021-11-23"
  }
]
```

here is the Playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/4UtuONJiL6Z

I need with :

```
userID : ObjectId("61965bead6af120015c7e9cc")
date: new Date() //ISODate("2021-11-25T16:08:35.606Z") for example
```

=> nothing

and :

```
userID : ObjectId("61965bead6af120015c7e9cc")
date: new Date() //ISODate("2021-11-26T16:08:35.606Z")
```

results :

```
[
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        userId:ObjectId("61965bead6af120015c7e9cc"),
        date: ISODate("2021-11-25T16:04:35.606Z"),
        ip: "100.000.000.0"
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("11934e000102030405000111"),
        userId:ObjectId("61965bead6af120015c7e9cd"),
        date: ISODate("2021-11-25T14:08:32.992Z"),
        ip: "200.000.000.0"
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("645465454565465465465465"),
        userId:ObjectId("61965bead6af120015c7e9cc"),
        date: ISODate("2021-11-26T16:08:35.606Z"),
        ip: "100.000.000.0"
      },
    ]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by ***"...AND if date is not the same day as the date in mongo"*** ?

Comment: and also tell if `userId` is unique or not?

Comment: @TalESid
"...AND if date is not the same day as the date in mongo" => YES
userId is unique

Comment: means update the `date` value if (user exist & date saved in mongodb is not of today i.e. `new Date()` ) ?

Comment: Instead of `$dateToString` I would rather suggest [$dateTrunc({units: 'day'})](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/)

Comment: dateinDB:{$dateTrunc: { date: "$date", unit: "day" } } ?

Comment: Still not clear what you are looking for. You have 2 documents, your results has 3 documents. That has noting to do with "update, create or replace some field" - that's an `insertOne()`

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit
Yes sorry you're wright : compare current day with day in mongodb and insertOne()
can I change title ?

Comment: Yes, you can change the title. However, I still don't understand the requirement. What is 'req.socket.remoteAddress' or 'req.user._id'

Comment: I can't do with aggregate but with update : https://mongoplayground.net/p/s4C_Bme8-h7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    
      $project: 
      {              
          dateinDB:{$dateToString: {date:"$date",format:"%Y-%m-%d"}},
          current:{$dateToString: {date:new Date(),format:"%Y-%m-%d"}}
      }
  },
   { $addFields: {
      date: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: ["$userId",'$req.user._id'] },
          then: {
            $cond: {
              if:{$ne: [ "$dateinDB" ,"$current"]},
              then :{$date:"$current"}
            }
          },
          else: {
            'userId': '$req.user._id',
            'date': new Date(),
            'ip':'$req.socket.remoteAddress'
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  
]);
```

Comment: thanks, its close,
https://mongoplayground.net/p/aw3iy2uiK3L
=> query failed: (InvalidPipelineOperator) Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$date'

Comment: sorry it's not the good way what I did, see the result : https://mongoplayground.net/p/4UtuONJiL6Z
the result must be the same as the start with new entry (new _id same as the other) or nothing.